# Why not initiating the iterator the child loop makes it stop after one parent completed loop?

Tags: c++

If I didn't initiate the iterators *i* and *j* with zero's this is what happens. The compiler does initiate them by zeros but somehow the child loop didn't proceed with iterating. Any interpretation for that?

I already found the solution but I am asking about what could be the reason behind this?

```
void sortById(int *arr,  int size){
    for (int i; i<size; i++){
        cout << "i = " << i << "\n" ;
        for (int j; j<size; j++){
            cout << "j = " << j << "\n";
        }
     }
}

int main(){
int Ids[5] = {15,3,1,10,25};
int size = 5;

sortById(Ids, size);
}


//Output:
i = 0 
j = 0 
j = 1 
j = 2 
j = 3 
j = 4 
i = 1 
i = 2 
i = 3 
i = 4
```

Comment: undefined behavior. The compiler doesn't initiate them by zeroes, but by *garbage values*, which happen to be zeroes in your case.

Tip: Enable warnings.

Comment: Please explain "the child loop didn't proceed with iterating". What is the child loòp? What means "proceed with iterating"?

Comment: How often do you expect the compiler to do the initialising for you? Once? Every time the inner loop starts?

Comment: I am sorry for my namings. I mean by the parent loop here to be for (int i; i<size; i++) and the child loop to be for (int j; j<size; j++). proceed with iterating means that after *i* changed from *0* to *1* the child loop didn't iterate any more from *0* to *4* as it did when *i* was equal to *0*. I hope it is clear now?

Comment: What happens if you do `int j; std::cout << j << std::endl; for (; j<size; j++){` ? Does it act the same and give you more info?

Comment: well just having `int j; cout << "j = " << j << "\n";` gave me zero but having after it `for (; j<size; j++){cout << "j = " << j << "\n";}` gave me j with an undefined number overriding the 0. Thanks for your input.

Comment: So what makes you wonder about the described behaviour?

Comment: Could somebody please quote from standard, to support the "undefined behaviour" statement?

Comment: **Edited based on your reply for this comment** because the parent loop `for (int i; i<size; i++)` went on normally with no initialization as well from *0* to *4*, that is why I was confused.

Comment: Consider the questions in my second comment again, please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194736/discussion-between-mour-ka-and-yunnosch).

Comment: How often do you expect the compiler needs to init in order to make the outer loop continue normally? In contrast to how often init is needed in order to make inner loop act as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple words,
No, it does not initialize it to zero.

When memory is not cleared by previous programs and you try to initialize a variable inside a function, the memory associated with that variable is allocated in stack. And it does not initialize the value, it can hold any value (either used by a previous program or just zero).

This value is called “Garbage Value”.

Detailed explanation:

Every function, when compiled by the compiler,Then it has been divided into two sections:

1. Code Section.
2. Data Section.

The information on where the variable should be stored can be found in the storage class specifier. check this for more info on [storage class specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

And The storage class by default is at “auto”, which means that the variable is stored in the stack section of the function. When things are initialized in the stack, the value associated with that variable is unknown or “Garbage value”, meaning it may or may not be zero. There is no Guarantee either value can be assinged.

Answer (score 0):

Its because uninitialized variables have the value of the memory-segment theyre created on, which is normally garbage. So your loop may as well start at 0x2342FF